# Angular - How to display an array of objects in a table

Tags: angular

It seems like a fairly straightforward thing to achieve but cannot get this working:

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index">
        <td><input [formControl]="itemName"></td>
        <td>{{itemColour}}</td>
        <td>
            <button (click)="updateItemName()" displayIf =" * keypress in input field * ">Update</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myService.getItems().subscribe({
      next: data => {
        this.items = JSON.parse(data);
      },
      error: err => {
      }
    });
  }

updateItemName(): void {
    this.itemService.updateItemName(* The Item ID *, * The Item Name *); 
  }
```

The returned JSON looks like this:

```
{"items":[{"id":1,"itemName":"Name 1","itemColour":"Colour 1"},{"id":2,"itemName":"Name 2","itemColour":"Colour 2"}
```

I think this should be fairly straightforward but I've spent hours going round in circles on this, I have tried using formArray and formGroup.

Comment: What exactly is your issue. Is it not showing or are there errors?

Comment: Can you provide a log of how your returned JSON data from myService.getItems() looks like and the errors that you get?

Comment: JSON response added - thanks!

Comment: Create a FormGroup and add a FormControll in For-Loop in .component.ts, put the *ngFor in <form FormCotroll> - hope this helps

Comment: This sounds great Flo - I tried something like this though was struggling with the syntax to get it to work, would be ok to quickly write it out?

Answer (score 0):

As you have shared json of your API response, your response is not a list of objects, instead contains items property which is a list of objects. So you can do something like following:

```
this.myService.getItems().subscribe({
  next: data => {
    let response = JSON.parse(data);
    this.items = response.items;
  },
  error: err => {}
});
```

Also, in Angular it is not mendatory to parse the incoming string, So I think following may also work:

```
this.myService.getItems().subscribe({
  next: data => {
    this.items = data.items;
  },
  error: err => {}
});
```

**Update:**
You can use [(ngModel)] instead of FormControl, like this:

```
 <input [(ngModel)]="item.itemName">
```

And you can pass item's reference to get the value:

```
<button (click)="updateItemName(item)">Update</button>
```

You need to change your method to accept item argument and make it something like this:

```
  updateItemName(item: any): void {
    this.itemService.updateItemName(item.id, item.itemName).subscribe({
       next: (response) => {
          // Show a message or something when response is success.
       },
       error: (error) => {
         // Maybe you can show an error message, if the response was not OK.
       }
    });
  }
```

Comment: This is great thanks! Though how do I match this up to the frontend so that the input value is accessible when clicking the button on each row?

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can check it. Also please let me know if there is still anything unclear to you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to change itemName inside items array, you can simply use [(ngModel)]="item.itemName" instead of formControl

<input [(ngModel)]="item.itemName">

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index">
        <td><input [(ngModel)]="item.itemName"></td>
        <td>{{itemColour}}</td>
        <td>
            <button (click)="updateItemName(item)" displayIf =" * keypress in input field * ">Update</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Inside component.ts

```
updateItemName(item): void {
    this.itemService.updateItemName(item.id, item.itemName).subscribe(); 
  }
```